# Is there a way to get a Unix timestamp in Stata?

Tags: stata

I searched online and found [several](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2002-09/msg00518.html) [sources](http://log.tofias.net/post/486823675/time-stamp-in-stata) that talk about converting Unix timestamps to various workable formats, but none that allow me to actually get such a timestamp from within Stata. As of now, I use variations on

```
local curr_date = c(current_date)
local curr_time = c(current_time)
```

to apply timestamps to logs, data sets, etc. but I'd like to just use the Unix timestamp in seconds, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with [help datetime](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?datetime)? My understanding is that the Unix time stamp would be something like

```
display %12.0g clock("`c(current_date)' `c(current_time)'", "DMY hms" )/1000 - clock("1 Jan 1970", "DMY" )/1000
```

which of course you can use in other circumstances as well. (I am not a C programmer, I am a Stata user, but I do understand that it is easier for most people on this site to write [a snippet of C code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11688606/874882) that would go into the guts of Stata than to RTFM... which is admirable in its own ways from where I sit, of course.)

Comment: That's a neat feature that I didn't see when I read the documentation, but I noticed something odd when using it. I used that Stata command, followed a split second later by the `time.time()` command in Python, which is known to be accurate, and your Stata command, and the Stata command is about **18,000** seconds behind, which is not usable if I need an accurate timestamp. I tried the same test with the C `time` function and saw similar results.

Comment: I don't have my plugin with me at the moment, but I'll use both commands in a do file this evening and measure the difference, if any. That way the time between each run of the command will only be a few milliseconds, instead of 1 or 2 seconds when I test it manually. Even including those few seconds, though, is not enough to explain the difference I don't think.

Comment: 18000 seconds difference sounds a lot like 5 time zones difference to me. Which is to say, your computer runs either New York or Tashkent local time rather than the GMT time.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Is there a way for me to change the timezone Stata uses (since I can't change the system timezone in my office)? I'm hesitant to simply add 5 hours to the time.

Comment: Since it's somewhat related, how would I store this in a macro? `local unixTime display %12.0g clock("`c(current_date)' `c(current_time)'", "DMY hms" )/1000 - clock("1 Jan 1970", "DMY" )/1000` doesn't work because it only evaluates the statement once.

Comment: I think a better way to get this done would be via `class` returns. Stata class system is ugly, to put it mildly. But basically you will have a one-line function with the above code. Try it, if you can't make it work, come back, and I will give more pointers.

Comment: When you say `class` returns, you are referring to `return/creturn`, etc., correct? I can store the value in a macro like so: local unixTime = clock("`c(current_date)' `c(current_time)'", "DMY hms" )/1000 - clock("1 Jan 1970", "DMY" )/1000   but I can't figure out what you mean by using `class` returns, since `return/creturn/ereturn` are all empty after I use that command.

Comment: What I meant was to use Stata `class`es that, to the first approximation, act like macros. `*return` is a part of the story, but not the whole story. `class return` creates a macro that you can use inline, without having to call a program... which saves you a line of code, and arguably a little bit in readability of the code if you name it right :).

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to write a simple plugin. Compile this code, in a file called `unixtimestamp.c`

```
#include "stplugin.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

STDLL stata_call(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    time_t seconds;
    seconds = time(NULL);
    char buf[33];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", seconds);

    SF_display(buf);
    return(0);
}
```

with [stplugin.h](http://www.stata.com/plugins/stplugin.h) and [stplugin.c](http://www.stata.com/plugins/stplugin.c) in the same directory using this command (for a Linux system):

```
gcc -O3 -shared -DSYSTEM=OPUNIX -fPIC stplugin.c unix_timestamp.c -o unixtimestamp.plugin
```

The [guide](http://www.stata.com/plugins/#sect5b) to creating plugins uses this command:

```
gcc -shared -DSYSTEM=OPUNIX stplugin.c unixtimestamp.c -o unixtimestamp.plugin
```

but on some systems, this gives an error instructing you to use the `-fPIC` flag, which is why I include it in my command. Also, optimizations aren't really necessary for such a simple plugin, but I included them regardless.

`unixtimestamp.plugin` should be placed in the `ado/personal/` directory. Run Stata's `sysdir` function to find its location. On my system, it's `HOME/ado/personal/` so I copied the plugin there. Then, from Stata, load the plugin:

```
program unixtimestamp, plugin
```

If no error message is displayed, run the plugin with:

```
plugin call unixtimestamp
```

As with any Stata command, you can also use a macro to simplify this if you plan to use this command frequently:

```
local unixtime plugin call unixtimestamp
`unixtime'
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following to grab a date/time stamp:

```
di "DateTime: $S_DATE $S_TIME"
```

**Updated:**
You may use Unix shell commands directly inside Stata by prefixing them an exclamation mark. To echo Unix time try:

```
!date +%s
1344341160
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my question was clear enough. I already have a way to get the timestamp in that format, but I needed a Unix timestamp in seconds. The commands in my original question that use `creturn` already give me a timestamp in this format.